# prove that the no of normal subgroups of a fixed order containing K is congruent to 1 mod p.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a p group K is a normal subgroup of G of order p to the power a. Then prove that the no of normal subgroups of a fixed order containing K is congruent to 1 mod p.

I've proved that the no of subgroups of a fixed order containing K is congruent to 1 mod p.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. For example, $D_8$ is a $2$-group, and has a non-normal subgroup $K$ order 2 made up of the identity and a reflection... in which case the number of normal subgroups of order $2$ containing $K$ is $0$

Comment: I am sorry K will be normal subgroup. Typo sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Check the answer.
I've proved that the no of subgroups of a fixed order containing K is congruent to 1 mod p.
Now K is normal in G & G is a p group. Then we can act on the set S, containing all the subgroups of fixed order containing K(see, the set is non empty!!), by conjugation of elements of G.
From the class equation derived from this action we have p|(|S|-|Sg|) [as G is a p-group],
where Sg={H : g.H=H}. So Sg here is nothing but the set containing all normal subgroups of fixed order containing K. 
So, |Sg| is congruent to 1 (mod p). Proved.